# Docker container with licensed software

Tags: docker

I have 6 servers running a licensed software (license is based on mac-address), i want to convert these to 1 server that on demand run one or more docker containers with the software. How I can manage the license in the containers?

Comment: How can this be answered without knowing anything about the software, the license, the OS, the efforts and things you already tried?

Comment: Unless you're planning to write the software yourself (and I don't see any suggestion in that direction), this is off-topic for StackOverflow.